Trying to solve a large system of highly stiff differential equations in JULIA language
I have a system of differential equations containing 62500 simultaneous equations. The system dynamics are linear and of the form:
[dU/dt] = [Jacobian]x[U].
The jacobian is sparse (non-zero vals ~ 0.6%) and banded. However, the system is also highly stiff. The largest value in the Jacobian matrix is roughly 1E12 and the smallest nonzero value is probably around 1E3 so I'm using an implicit solver: CVODE_BDF with GMRES as the linear solver.
A brief description of the physics: I am trying to solve a nanometric species transport problem. Assume a nanometric cuboid box (25nm x 25nm x100nm), where the bottom face of the box has an initial distribution of species. With time, the species hop and transport to the top face of the box.
Note: This problem is a reduced version of a larger original problem. I have reduced it to an extent below which is physically meaningless to solve this problem. The original problem contains ~ 500k - 1 Million simultaneous differential equations of similar form.
Uploading my code and data file for reference.
The code and data file is in the drive link :
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/15njIqjrZ2hwl1rEuVYYin59vINlZkQwI
However, this method results in convergence failures from the solver. I have tried reducing the tolerances till reltol =1E-10 and abstol = 1E-7. I'm still not obtaining satisfactory results and convergence failures still occur. Currently, I am trying alternative solvers such as: QNDF, FBDF etc., . I will update on those results soon.

Please provide a minimal, reproducible example with necessary code and data posted in the question so we can see what you are trying to do.

"Julia discourse"? you crossposted this and just copy-pasted the post's output here, without making sure your uploads came along?

@PaSTE The code and data are available in the link: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/15njIqjrZ2hwl1rEuVYYin59vINlZkQwI

Please post the code that is causing problems in the question itself, and make sure you reduce it to the minimal code necessary to reproduce the problem. Reducing the code to the key line or lines that cause the problem is an effective way to debug the problem in itself and may allow you to answer your own questions. Also, you can't expect people to download 350 MB of data to help you solve this: try reducing the data to the minimum set that reproduces the problem; or, if it's volume of data that is the problem, write code to generate enough random data to reproduce it and post that, too.

since OP got his answer on discourse.julialang.org, I don't see much benefit in trying to help this question along. someone could pick up the solution from the discourse and post it here, or just vote to close this question

Didnt get the answer yet @ChristophRackwitz.

Yes I will do that @PaSTE. I will Upload a minimum code.

you posted an answer here (now deleted) that literally says "The solution thread is here: Please visit link" pointing to the aforementioned julia discourse thread that contains a post by yourself that says "Very well explained. Thank you!!!."

@ChristophRackwitz Probably you injured your head and were not aware of the later comments. I only said I will try those methods and let know how it works. Now give me a sound solution or atleast let others provide it. Stop spamming the thread. Also, Im not taking this post down until I get a solution.

thanks a lot for helping me clear this problem.
As i mentioned before,: I am trying to solve a nanometric species transport problem. Where the species have to travel from the bottom face of a cuboid box (25nm x 25nm x100nm) to the top face (where they exit). I inspected the jacobian matrix carefully and i came to understand that at some elements, the influx rate was orders higher than the outflux rate. This did not let the possibility of species decay/transport out of that element (if they flow out they will be pushed back into that element). This was the main reason for ODE solver failure.
I Identified the specific locations where this occured and added an additional decay mode to the existing dynamics to force the species to decay in such elements. Now after doing the same, CVODE_BDF works just fine. QNDF also works fine. Exponential solvers Exprb32 and 43 are extremely slow for the working problem. It was more of a Physics related issue than an ODE-related issue.
.
@Paste, thanks a lot for trying to help.
